# Multilist with Search fields with duplicate items

Tags: fieldtype

We have one problem in Sitecore.

Whenever we use the "Multilist with Search" fields, the same item is displayed multiple times with different versions. And the content editor is able to select same items multiple times. Not sure why it is?

Please provide some help here so that we can get the latest version in "Multilist with Search" and so can chooose the latest version of the item.

Answer (score 3):

To get the latest item version in the Multilist with Search field, you need to apply the following filter to the Multilist with Search field source:

```
Filter=_latestversion:true
```

Please try and see if it works fine.

Comment: I have tried and seems to be working but in case of any issues, will create another question. Thanks, Rohit